# How to use objects as input values with Knockout.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I want to use an observableArray as the default tags in a select2 plugin, but I´m struggling with both getting the context right and setting the plug-in in the right way.

Here is the html:

```
<div data-bind="with: SelectedText">
    <h1>Title: <span data-bind="text: Title"></span></h1>
    <div>
        <label>A: Local Managers:</label>
        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: managerTags, select2: { tags: $root.Tags, minimumInputLength: 1, tokenSeparators: [',', ' '] }">        
        <label>B: Global Managers:</label>
        <input type="hidden" data-bind="value: $root.managerTags, select2: { tags: $root.promans, minimumInputLength: 1, tokenSeparators: [',', ' '] }">

        C: Local  Selected: <span data-bind="text: managerTags"></span>
        D: Global Selected: <span data-bind="text: $root.managerTags"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

See full fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6cWDX/

Why is the context of "A: Local Managers " not working for "C: Local Selected "?
How can I use the array of Tag objects (self:Tags) as an option to the select2 plugin?

Comment: Your full fiddle is huge tbh. If I just use the code from your question with a mock view model everything [is working as expected](http://jsfiddle.net/M56V3/). Please narrow down your example and try to edit the question so it contains a full (but short as possible) repro, this will make it a lot easier for us to help you.

Comment: The issue is the tags and their context when a text batch is selected. See updated fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/mDufq/2/

Answer (score 1):

Actually, both $root.SelectedText.managerTags and managerTags produce the same result in the context of your snippet (SelectedText), as you would expect. The reason it's not working the same way on $root.managerTags as it is on $root.SelectedText.managerTags, is that the former is an array of strings, where the latter is an array of objects:

```
    Local  Selected: <span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(managerTags)"></span>
    <br>
    Global Selected: <span data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root.managerTags)"></span>
```

Results in:

Local Selected: [{"Id":1,"Name":"Ronald","Type":0},{"Id":4,"Name":"George","Type":0}] 
Global Selected: "Asle,Jørgen"

Edit:
The difference you're noticing between A and C is that this:

```
$root.SelectedText.managerTags
```

does not work, since SelectedText is observable. Doing this:

```
$root.SelectedText().managerTags
```

WILL produce the same results for A and C

Comment: You might be right in theory, but I can´t get it to work in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mDufq/5/

Comment: You didn't fix either of the two issues in the fiddle you just linked. I fixed the second one for you, now you're seeing [object object] instead of strings. This is due to the first problem, which I leave to you because I don't know this select2 plugin you're using. The problem is in the datastructure you're passing into the select2 binding. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mDufq/8/

Comment: Obviously my title on this question is wrong. My problem here is how to present array-attributes with knockout, as I need the presentation to follow the data model and not the other way around.